# Move Linux (Mint) to another partition

Tags: partitioning, linux-mint, migration

I currently have Mint 19 on a 70 GB partition (see below). It is the last one on this drive. I need more space for it, so I deleted the partition before that. Now I need to move the whole sda3 partition to this empty space, and then merge the two partitions to one (or is there another way?).

Is there a good way to do that? I'm not sure how to safely move the whole system from one partition to another?

My thought was to create a new partition on the free space and simply restore a Macrium or Acronis backup image to it, then delete sda3 and merge it into the new one? Is there a better way?

[image: Gparted output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Expand partition with a new partition on the left or preceding sectors](https://superuser.com/questions/542389/how-to-expand-partition-with-a-new-partition-on-the-left-or-preceding-sectors)

Comment: The other question is similar, but due to the specific circumstances I think the solution is not the same. I'm trying to resize my system partition, so I cannot do what the answer to the other question suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start doing things with disks like this *ALWAYS* make a backup first.

As I see it, the easiest way would be:

- create an USB-stick with a bootable Linux.
- boot from that stick
- check your drives

(your drive-name sda might now be sdb or ...; I will call it sdX for the remainder)

- with `fdisk`, create the partition /dev/sdX4 that is 75.99 GB and make it bootable
- `dd if=/dev/sdX3 of=/dev/sdX4 status=progress`
- get some coffee
- update your bootmanager (lilo, grub or what you use) to i; nclude booting from sda4
- boot from sda4. See that everything works and that all your data is there

Upto here, you haven't destroyed anything yet. That is the next step :-)

- boot again from the USB-disk
- MAKE VERY SURE YOU HAVE THE RIGHT NAME FOR sdX
- make a copy on paper of the partition-table.
- delete partition sdX3
- take a deep breath, recheck that you have a paper version of the old partition table and with `fdisk`, delete partition sdX4
- create a new partition /dev/sdX3, with exactly the same start as the old sdX4 but in size the 150G ID=83.
- revisit your boot-manager and make sure that it boots from the new sda3
- reboot from sda3
- login and do `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda3`

And that should be it.

Comment: Ok.... I follow up to the copy part, but the next steps seem unnecessarily risky!? I guess what this should do is keep the data but make a bigger partition around it? Can't I simply resize the new partition with Gparted or whatever? Why delete and recreate the partition?

Comment: you delete a recreate (larger) , because you want a larger filesystem. The important part is that the new partition you create has exactly the same start. It is still the easiest way to get the partition-table exactly as you want it.

Comment: Hm. I think I will try your solution, which is more or less what I thought it would be (thanks for the dd!), but stick to GParted or something similar for the resizing. Don't see why I should take that risk.

Comment: So I did it. Followed your method up until dd and updating grub (with boot-repair as that was easier to use on the live cd). Then booted into the new partition, used GParted to delete the old partition and merge the two into one. Then booted again into the now only Mint partition, and did the resize2fs (but it turns out GParted already took care of that). The only difference in outcome to your method is that my root partition is still on /dev/sda4 and there is now no sda3. But I can live with that :)